# hibernate mapping using annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

i have two tables like this.

```
Company
       company_id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
       name varchar(200) not null

Employee
       employee_id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
       company_id int(11) not null,
       employee_name varchar(50) not null,
       foreign key(company_id) references Company(company_id) on updade cascade on delete cascade
```

Now i want to access employee information as well as company information only using

```
from Employee
```

with the hibernate. I am new in hibernate i dont know which method will be used. either join table, primary key join or any other. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your table, it appears that a company can have many employees, and an employee can only work for one company. I see that you have a company_id foreign key in your employees table. You do not have a join table.

So you will want to set up your objects to reflect this database structure. Create a Company class and an Employee class. Also give Company a Set<Employee> field.

Then set up Hibernate with a basic bidirectional one-to-many relationship from Company to Employee.

Hibernate will handle generating the SQL for you (FYI it uses cross joins by default for one-to-many and many-to-one relationships, although you can set it to generate serial selects instead if you want).

You wouldn't want a join table unless you had a many-to-many Company-to-Employee relationship (and in that case you wouldn't want a company_id foreign key in employees).